# jquery: reliable plugin for jquery 1.4 that allows ajax file upload

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload

Could you point me to some tested `jquery` plugin for `ajax` file upload? I would like it to be `jquery 1.4` compliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several listed here:  http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2010/02/10-best-ajax-file-uploader-for-your-web-application/

Comment: There are lots of cool uploadres, but all I need is only an uploading plugin, not progress bars, etc. Could you suggest me anything like this? Just like `$.ajax`, but for files.

Comment: Perhaps this? http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/

Comment: This allows choosing multiple files, not uploading them.